# Somehow invalid Peer was used

Tags: python, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection, utils, types
import asyncio
import socks
import random
import time
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChat
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
B = []
A = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
b = int(len(A) - 1)
api_id = 
api_hash = 
async def groups():
    async with TelegramClient('3', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '', , True, '', '')) as client:
        async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
            if dialog.is_group:
                chat = await client.get_input_entity(dialog.id)
                print('{:>14}: {}'.format(dialog.id, dialog.title))
                print(chat)
                B.append(chat)
    return B
asyncio.run(groups())
async def main():
    for i in B:
        u = len(B) - 1
        for i in range(u):
            u -= 1
            x = B[u]
            print(x)
            print(u)
            async with TelegramClient('3', api_id, api_hash, proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '', 64275, True, '', '')) as client:
                await client.send_message(x, message=str(A[random.randint(0, b)]))
        time.sleep(20)
asyncio.run(main())
```

```
How does the entity looks like? InputPeerChat(chat_id=1234567)?. Tell me how to make my code work plz.
This is repost of an old question(nobody helped)
```

I tried to use ids, not the entities. Didnt work either. Access hash is not required for chats(groups).
apis are correct as well as proxy.
Explain plz.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code, add white space for readability. Make sure it compiles. Make the title more descriptive. "Didn't work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].